# How to update or overload a selenium javascript prototype function?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, record

I want to enhance the record function in the Recorder object.

I want to put it into an extension.

Recorder.prototype.record = My new function here

Will just putting my function there and putting this in a user extension file be enough or is it much more complicated?

Comment: Are you asking about extending the Selenium IDE recorder? Please provide us with more information, including the language you are using, and some code that you are examining.

Comment: Yes, exactly Javascript.